# css class not working mvc visual studio

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have declare a class in my site.css file as follows:

```
.CMenu1 {
  display:inline;
}
```

Then I have tried to use that class to style my list in Index.cshtml like so:

```
<ul class="CMenu1">
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Bananas</li>
  <li>Lemons</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
</ul>
```

However when I run the solution it continues to show the default style for a list, why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the css to the `<li>` elements to make them inline.

```css
.CMenu1 li{
  display:inline;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="CMenu1">
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Bananas</li>
  <li>Lemons</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for a solution to a problem other than what OP have asked for -
Sometimes the class is not added to the `Site.css` even after rebuilding the project. The problem here is that `Site.css` is not getting updated in the project even though we have modified it. In this case, `clean` followed by `rebuild` or `build` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

class is already a built in property in c#, so in order to make that read you need to put

`@class`:

```
<ul @class="CMenu1">
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Bananas</li>
  <li>Lemons</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
</ul>
```